# Kafka Burrow stops after running for a while with error "fatal error: concurrent map writes"

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka burrow keeps stops after running for a while. I am using email and slack notifiers. I tried changing configuration multiple times but it always dies after 3-4 hours.

Below is the error in the log file:

```
Started Burrow at December 24, 2016 at 11:52pm (ICT)
2016/12/24 23:52:42 Connected to 10.117.170.5:2181
2016/12/24 23:52:42 Connected to 10.117.170.5:2181
2016/12/24 23:52:42 Authenticated: id=241180442484362689, timeout=40000
2016/12/24 23:52:42 Re-submitting 0 credentials after reconnect
2016/12/24 23:52:42 Authenticated: id=241180442484362690, timeout=40000
2016/12/24 23:52:42 Re-submitting 0 credentials after reconnect
2016/12/25 00:07:26 http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls
fatal error: concurrent map writes

goroutine 961935 [running]:
runtime.throw(0xad2a00, 0x15)
/usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/panic.go:547 +0x90 fp=0xc8211dec10 sp=0xc8211debf8
runtime.mapassign1(0x8a5400, 0xc82025ff50, 0xc8211ded48, 0xc8211dee08)
/usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/hashmap.go:445 +0xb1 fp=0xc8211decb8 sp=0xc8211dec10
github.com/linkedin/Burrow/notifier.(*SlackNotifier).Notify(0xc820b4a090, 0xc82014b520, 0x7, 0xc82016a4b0, 0x2c, 0x1, 0x1, 0xd7cc40, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
/opt/goprojects/src/src/github.com/linkedin/Burrow/notifier/slack_notifier.go:76 +0x383 fp=0xc8211dee70 sp=0xc8211decb8
main.(*NotifyCenter).handleEvaluationResponse(0xc820b50420, 0xc82041e660)
/opt/goprojects/src/src/github.com/linkedin/Burrow/notify_center.go:117 +0xe4 fp=0xc8211defa0 sp=0xc8211dee70
runtime.goexit()
/usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1998 +0x1 fp=0xc8211defa8 sp=0xc8211defa0
created by main.StartNotifiers
/opt/goprojects/src/src/github.com/linkedin/Burrow/notify_center.go:95 +0x398

goroutine 1 [chan receive, 228 minutes]:
main.burrowMain(0x0)
/opt/goprojects/src/src/github.com/linkedin/Burrow/main.go:154 +0x2155
main.main()
/opt/goprojects/src/src/github.com/linkedin/Burrow/main.go:162 +0x57

goroutine 17 [syscall, 228 minutes, locked to thread]:
runtime.goexit()
/usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1998 +0x1

goroutine 5 [semacquire, 228 minutes]:
sync.runtime_Syncsemacquire(0xc820053b10)
/usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/sema.go:241 +0x201
sync.(*Cond).Wait(0xc820053b00)
/usr/lib/golang/src/sync/cond.go:63 +0x9b
github.com/cihub/seelog.(*asyncLoopLogger).processItem(0xc8200886c0, 0x0)
/opt/goprojects/src/src/github.com/cihub/seelog/behavior_asynclooplogger.go:50 +0xee
github.com/cihub/seelog.(*asyncLoopLogger).processQueue(0xc8200886c0)
/opt/goprojects/src/src/github.com/cihub/seelog/behavior_asynclooplogger.go:63 +0x40
created by github.com/cihub/seelog.NewAsyncLoopLogger
/opt/goprojects/src/src/github.com/cihub/seelog/behavior_asynclooplogger.go:40 +0x91
```

Comment: I had exactly the same error in version 0.1.1
After the update to version 1.0.0 (https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow/releases/tag/v1.0.0), which came out the other day the errors are no more.
I recommend that you update, in the last release, a lot of problems were solved.